# How to get the pointer of an item from a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

It is not complicated to search for an item in a linked list and return it: just browse a copy of the list and return the item that matches the search predicate. However, I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve the pointer of the element we are looking for in the list, which implies a difficulty I have not been able to overcome: there can be no copy of the original list (otherwise the pointer would be invalid or would not match an item in the original list).

I chose the structure of the linked list because I need a lot of additions and deletions, which an array allows to do, but in a less efficient way. Nevertheless, I would like to be able to modify some elements of my list; to do this I had imagined such a function:

```
struct Item
{
    char* str;
    int value;
};

typedef struct Node
{
    struct Item item;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node *push(Node *head, const struct Item)
{
    Node *new_node;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    new_node->item = item;
    new_node->next = head;
    head = new_node;
    return head;
}

Node *remove(Node *head, char* str)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if (!strcmp(head->item.str, str))
    {
        Node *tmp_next = head->next;
        free(head);
        return tmp_next;
    }

    head->next = remove(head->next, str);
    return head;
}

struct Item *get_item_ptr(const Node *head, char* str)
{
    // I would get the pointer of the structure Item that refers to the string `str`.
    ...
    return NULL; // I return `NULL` if no item meets this predicate.
}
```

I don't know how to do that while keeping the original linked list intact and I'm not sure it's a good idea, in which case I'd be reduced to a simple array (or another more suitable data structure?).

Comment: You return the address of the `struct Item` where you find the match, or `NULL` if not found. For example `return &node->item;` This is simpler than your "search a *copy* of the list".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the function should be defined something like

```
struct Item * get_item_ptr( const Node *head, const char *str )
{
    while ( head != NULL && strcmp( head->item.str, str ) != 0 )
    {
        head = head->next;
    }

    return head == NULL ? ( struct Item * )NULL : &head->item; 
}
```

Comment: It's something like that I had thought of, however the point would be to keep the linked list intact, that's what makes the problem more complicated. Maybe I wasn't specific enough in my question, I'll edit it.

Comment: @Foxy What do you mean saying that  the linked list  has to be intact? The linked list is not changed by this function.

Comment: Excuse me, indeed it does work. I thought the body of the loop was changing the list, but it's not. Thank you for your answer!